# Does technological advance necessarily start a war between men and women in a dystopian future?

Tags: warfare, far-future, dystopia, gender, inequality

Technology of the future is likely to remove the differences of possessing power, strength and resources between genders. Moreover, it is likely that one gender becomes completely independent on biological function of the other, rendering them useless completely. Even the remaining romantic and friendship bonds are too thin to last more.
Do those factors inevitably lead to a full fledged war between genders?

Comment: Please reword the question to be not so open ended brain storm request. Please checkout the [help](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help). You would be able to get much better answers if you asked: I want war in setup X, is scenario Y plausible to cause war?

Comment: Genders do not have biological functions. Sexes do. And you may want to explain how come that in the radiant future when differences are removed, and thus everybody is pretty much as powerful, as strong and as resourceful as anybody else, they would somehow chose to follow one flag or another and fight a war. A war for what? When everybody is pretty much as powerful, as strong and as resourceful as anybody else, what is there to be gained from fighting a war?

Comment: @AlexP you have forgotten females comprise 72% of the planet's population, effectively rendering your whole thesis false; and this number will most likely be rising, as there are many benefits of NOT being a male

Comment: (a) If tech removes the differences between genders, it would also remove the differences between class and nations. But the point you've forgotten is that access to tech is today and will likely in the future remain unevenly accessible. If your future can provide equal access to tech, what's to create a war in the first place? Not lack of resources. (b) Your assertion that one gender will become biologically independent of the other (obviously women) isn't likely at all. But let's assume it is through something like (\*Continued\*)

Comment: ... synthetic sperm, then why have a war? Women simply control the gender of their children and no more men are born. 100 years later... no men. (c) But, to the real point, would it cause a war? Only if you, the author, wants it to happen. Per our [help/on-topic], our goal is to help you create an imaginary world of your own creation. Thus, we don't answer questions like this (Nosajimiki...). On the other hand, *make your choice* then ask us how to bring that choice to pass. That we will do, if you ask a specific enough question.

Answer (score 1):

### Your Setup is Fundamentally Flawed

> one gender becomes completely independent on biological function of the other, rendering them useless completely.

This will lead to peace, not war.  By making men and women are no longer interdependent on each other through sexual dimorphism and no longer care about romantic relationships, you've eliminated everything in our society that puts men and women at odds. Even though we don't need each other for sex and companionship anymore, we would all be productive members of the same society working towards common goals.  This means your relationships between men and women would become less complicated and more laid back like the relationships between men with men or women with women.

If you want men and women to go to war in your setting, you need one to remain reliant on the other for something.  When you need someone for something, it makes you want to control them.  Control makes that person resentful.  Resentment leads to revolution. So to figure out an answer to your question, you need to add a crack in your setup.  Something left over that technology can not replace that makes one gender still need the other, and with that need, you will have your cause for war.

Comment: according to Crowd Psychology, societies consisting of almost identical individuals are extremely controllable and unbalanced; even a small lack of resources for a short period of time can start a brutal conflict between minorities and the dominant power; notice i never said all genders will be equal in their representation, and it is highly unlikely that all genders will be equally advantageous to belong to, anyway

Comment: @ivan866 If one gender is more advantageous to belong to, then that is in line with my answer.  The advantageous gender will only be advantageous because it in some way exploits the other gender.  But, to exploit someone is to make yourself reliant on them and therefore not useless at all.  Also, Crowd Psychology is the study of how people follow the will of a mob over thier own typical ideologies, so I think you are mixing up your terminology or misunderstand Crowd Psychology .  Crowd Psychology says that in a group of mostly similar people, they will all act the same.